# Getting null while reading Hyperlink from excel using poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have one excel file in which a row contains few cell as string and other as numeric, hyperlink.

I want to read the data from excel for that I wrote below code

```
HSSFCell cell =row.getCell(j+1);    
cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
String cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
```

above code reads numeric cells and string cells but when it comes to the cells which contain a hyperlink, in that case, it is reading those cells as null.I can put my hyperlink between double quotes("abc@cd.com") in the sheet but I want to handle this on the code level. Is there any way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use cell.[getHyperlink()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#getHyperlink()) to get a hyperlink from the cell.

```java
if(cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING){
    Hyperlink hyperlink = cell.getHyperlink();
    String value = cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
    if(hyperlink == null) {
        return value;
    } else {
        return value + " " + hyperlink.getAddress(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: How I can check whether cell contain hyperlink or not because every time it is not necessary that cell will contain hyperlink?

Comment: It will return you null if the cell doesn't contain a hyperlink. I don't think there is a Boolean value that you can use. Also it is possible for a cell to have both a hyperlink and a string cell value

Comment: I want to read in such a way if cell contains String then it should return string else if it contains hyperlink then it should return hyperlink value

Comment: Edited my answer. Is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks wai for your help